# Sharepoint list with Shareoint Performancepoint dashboard

Tags: list, performancepoint

how can i use Sharepoint list with Sharepoint Performancepoint Dashboard to generate graphical representation of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.
Its possible only by using Power Pivot for sharepoint and power pivot for excel. :D